# How do I make a method match the delegate 'WorkItemHandler' for WinRT threading?

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-8, threadpool

I'm trying to figure out Win8 C# threading, I know I should be using the ThreadPool class, but what I dont know is how to write my method to work with that.

```
IAsyncAction MainThread = Windows.System.Threading.ThreadPool.RunAsync(new WorkItemHandler(mainLoop));

public void mainLoop() { ... }
```

That's what my best attempt at this is so far, it's telling me no overload for mainLoop matches the WorkItemHandler delegate, but I have no idea what that means or how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that `mainLoop` must have the following [signature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.threading.workitemhandler):

```
public void mainLoop(
  IAsyncAction operation
)
```

You can quickly solve compiler errors you don't understand by Googling the message, optionally adding `site:stackoverflow.com`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you do have to have IAsyncAction signature, so I solved it with a lambda:

```
await ThreadPool.RunAsync(new WorkItemHandler((IAsyncAction) => workerMethod()));
```

Hope this helps.